# Why does Pytorch uses so much memory despite the tensor not being that big and not requiring gradients?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm having some unexpected out of memory issues when running a script locally that uses torch `1.13.1+cpu`.

Below is a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Why does it takes **10GB of RAM** and does not liberate it until the script ends? The acutal size of the tensor is quite small. What is taking that much memory and how can I prevent it / garbage collect it?

```
# memory_issue.py

import torch
from memory_profiler import profile
import sys

@profile
def get_random_tensor():
    t = torch.randn([3, 429, 1080, 1920], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=False)
    print(f"Allocated memory for tensor: {sys.getsizeof(t)} Bytes")
    return t

@profile
def permute_tensor(t):
    t = torch.permute(t, (3, 0, 1, 2))
    return t

@profile
def do_nothing(t):    
    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with torch.no_grad():
        my_tensor = get_random_tensor()
        my_tensor = permute_tensor(my_tensor)
        my_tensor = do_nothing(my_tensor)
```

When I run:

```
python memory_issue.py
```

This is the output:

```
Allocated memory for tensor: 72 Bytes

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     5    197.4 MiB    197.4 MiB           1   @profile
     6                                         def get_random_tensor():
     7  10379.1 MiB  10181.8 MiB           1       t = torch.randn([3, 429, 1080, 1920], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=False)
     8  10379.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(f"Allocated memory for tensor: {sys.getsizeof(t)} Bytes")
     9  10379.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return t


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    11  10379.1 MiB  10379.1 MiB           1   @profile
    12                                         def permute_tensor(t):
    13  10380.0 MiB      0.8 MiB           1       t = torch.permute(t, (3, 0, 1, 2))
    14  10380.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return t


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    16  10380.0 MiB  10380.0 MiB           1   @profile
    17                                         def do_nothing(t):    
    18  10380.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return t
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is not right. The tensor you created is a really big tensor.

`torch.randn([3, 429, 1080, 1920], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=False)`
means it occupies 3x429x1080x1920x4(float32 occupy 4 byte) = 10674892800 Bytes = 10GB memory space

Comment: You are right! I was totally misled by the output of `sys.getsizeof(t)` but that obviously does not work here..